# com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded

Tags: linux, java-7, jmockit

I get `AttachNotSupportedException`  while running jmockit tests on linux (ubuntu 64bit). Java version is 1.7.0_51. This  JDK is from Oracle. Tests are run using ant(that probably is not relevant)

See the stack trace.

```
[junit] 
[junit] java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:89)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:54)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.AgentInitialization.initializeAccordingToJDKVersion(AgentInitialization.java:21)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfNeeded(Startup.java:136)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfPossible(Startup.java:169)
[junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult.<clinit>(TestResult.java:15)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:356)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1165)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1016)
[junit] Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
[junit]     at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:79)
[junit]     ... 8 more
[junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:356)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1165)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:1016)
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:89)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.loadAgent(JDK6AgentLoader.java:54)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.AgentInitialization.initializeAccordingToJDKVersion(AgentInitialization.java:21)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfNeeded(Startup.java:136)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.initializeIfPossible(Startup.java:169)
[junit]     at junit.framework.TestResult.<clinit>(TestResult.java:15)
[junit]     ... 3 more
[junit] Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
[junit]     at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
[junit]     at mockit.internal.startup.JDK6AgentLoader.getVirtualMachineImplementationFromEmbeddedOnes(JDK6AgentLoader.java:79)
[junit]     ... 8 more
[junit] Running chs.caf.cap
```

It appears to be related to [AttachNotSupportedException while running jMockit tests on IBM JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205354/attachnotsupportedexception-while-running-jmockit-tests-on-ibm-jre). This however is on IBM jre.

Comment: There is a great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file

Comment: In my case it was due to launching jcmd with a different user from the one owning the running process. One of the cases described into https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963059/1996150

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Work around for now.

Adding `'-XX:+StartAttachListener'` to jvm argument fixed the issue.

A similar issue is discussed here at https://code.google.com/p/jmockit/issues/detail?id=136 and http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/macosx-port-dev/2013-October/006098.html  (which talks about a possible regression in jdk7 build)

Comment: Apparently, it's a bug in the Attach API implementation in this version of the Oracle JRE for Linux. It's likely already fixed in 1.7.0_60 and above.

Comment: This was actually still an issue for me in 1.8.0_131 on Linux

Answer (score 59):

I had the same issue while I was trying to dump threads using `jcmd`. I was getting same error message even though I was running `jcmd` under the `root` user.

You need to run `jcmd <pid> Thread.print` under the `same user as java process has`, otherwise your connections will be **dropped**. Java **doesn't care** if you are **root** or not.

So basically:

```
sudo -u <java_process_user> jcmd <pid> Thread.print
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for. However, with `Thread.dump` I get the following error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown diagnostic command`. I had to use `Thread.print`.

Comment: +100 THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: still facing the issue on java 8 (1.8.0_192).

Answer (score 6):

Like @bbarker, I got the same error but on JDK 1.8.0_161 using the Linux subsystem in Windows 10 ("Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"). Configuring the Surefire plugin with the JVM argument mentioned above fixed the issue for me as well:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>-XX:+StartAttachListener</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Running the tests from a "normal" Windows command prompt works without the above, though.

Answer (score 0):

I also got a similar problem when tried to check for Thread Deadlock. You can also use the command `jcmd <PID> Thread.print` to print the thread dump on the console and check if the program has a deadlock. You can check my answer with steps on [Deadlock detection in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217113/deadlock-detection-in-java/62519467#62519467)

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue, in my case, changing JDK vendor from `OPENJ9` to `OPENJDK` resolved the issue.