# jstack Format Change

Tags: java, analysis, jvm-hotspot

We have been using jstack to output thread dumps from our JVMs and for years we have been using the [IBM Thread Analyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=2245aa39-fa5c-4475-b891-14c205f7333c) to analyze the threads and monitors. Below is an example jstack (`jstack -l PID > jstack.out`) output that the analyzer parses.

```
Wed Oct  5 00:28:56 EDT 2016
2016-10-05 00:29:04
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000131e3800 nid=0x7654 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002ad5b81c1000 nid=0x717f waiting on condition [0x00002ad5d3d7e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache.run(KeepAliveCache.java:172)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

But some systems output a thread dump with the format below that the analyzer will not parse due to the format change of using dashes for the trace instead of white space. I have also tried to parse the file below with [TDA](https://github.com/irockel/tda) and [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html) with no luck.

```
Attaching to process ID 31283, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.91-b14
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 21765: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=215 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack$SNode, boolean, long) @bci=160, line=460 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(java.lang.Object, boolean, long) @bci=102, line=362 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) @bci=11, line=941 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() @bci=134, line=1066 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=26, line=1127 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Compiled frame)
```

My questions are:

1. Why is the format different? Is it the change from JVM version 24 to 25 (shown at the top of each output).
2. Is there a tool that will parse the new format or an undocumented jstack command that will output in the old format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably one of the dumps you took is with `-F` and the other is without. They are taken using the different mechanisms so outputs may vary.

Here's an example with -F

```
$ jstack -F 75540
Attaching to process ID 75540, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.45-b02
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.

Thread 14611: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 13571: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=59, line=143 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=164 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=36, line=209 (Interpreted frame)
```

And without

```
$ jstack 75540
2016-11-09 09:03:31
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f81e4000000 nid=0x5503 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f81e2815800 nid=0x5103 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

If you're curious, you can read more on the differences in [Running jmap getting Unable to open socket file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059). (Differences in output are just a consequence of that)

Comment: This is exactly my situation. Thank you.