# jmap - Does histo & heap operation bring overhead to jvm?

Tags: java, jvm, jmap

As the title states, how much overhead does `jmap -histo` and `jmap -heap` bring to a jvm respectively?

If a memory sensitive Java process is at the edge of `OutOfMemory` (e.g around 96% of heap is full, and can't be cleared by full gc), is it possible for one of the operations to bring the jvm to OutOfMemory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jmap -histo` and `jmap -heap` work differently: `jmap -histo` uses Dynamic Attach Mechanism, and `jmap -heap` works through HotSpot Serviceability Agent. The difference is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059).

Therefore, `jmap -histo` is executed by JVM itself, but `jmap -heap` runs in a tool process while JVM process is suspended. In both cases no new Java objects are created, the tool will not cause `OutOfMemoryError`.

In both cases application threads are stopped: `jmap -histo` stops Java threads, and `jmap -heap` stops the whole JVM process. The duration of the pause can be rather long especially for large heaps. E.g. it may take several seconds to walk through 4GB heap.

Comment: Any idea whether [`jcmd <process id/main class> GC.class_histogram`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) approach has the same impact?

Comment: @andyfeller `jcmd GC.class_histogram` works exactly like `jmap -histo`