# is JVM stopped while executing jmap -heap option?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, heap-dump, jmap

usage) Jmap -heap [PID]

Hello I have jmap question

I want to view only size (-heap option)
   Heap Dump No...

If I run [jmap -heap PID]  running jvm process is STOP THE WORLD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `jmap -heap` will cause stop-the-world pause. Moreover, not only application threads will be stopped, but the whole target process.

`jmap -heap` works through HotSpot Serviceability Agent which implies that the target process is suspended while a tool is running.

More details about how Serviceability Agent works are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963059/3448419).

Comment: thank you for your answer.

how about heap size search in btrace?

Comment: @ChulK How about [jstat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstat.html)? It has no overhead at all.