# How to get heap dump from java app running by HashiCorp Nomad?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump, nomad

I have java application that running by HashiCorp Nomad. At process status output I have nomad executor process running by `root` and java app process running by `nobody`.

When I try execute command: 
`jmap -dump:format=b,file=filename.bin <app_pid>`

I got message:

`Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding`

When I try execute command: `jmap -dump:format=b,file=filename.bin <app_pid> -F`

I got next trace:

`Attaching to core -F from executable 5584, please wait...
Error attaching to core file: cannot open binary file
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: cannot open binary file
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:286)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:673)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerLinux(HotSpotAgent.java:611)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:337)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:304)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:156)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:191)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jmap` without -F should be run by the same user as the target Java process (`nobody` in your case).

`jmap -F` should be run by root, and `-F` argument should precede `<app_pid>`:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=filename.bin -F <app_pid>
```

See details in [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059).