# Execute jstack with different user cause Full GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jstack

I start tomcat with tomcat user, and execute `jstack` with root user. I checked the gc log, find Full GC occur.

I search and find `sudo -u tomcat jstack -l <pid>` will solve the issue. But why jstack with root user will cause full gc?

**Environment:**

```
[root@bogon ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
[root@bogon ~]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
[root@bogon ~]# service tomcat version
vagrant: Display Tomcat Version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /apps/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /apps/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_65/
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
Server built:   Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC
Server number:  8.5.11.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_65-b17
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation



[root@bogon tomcat]# jstack -l 2644
2644: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

**GC logs**

```
CommandLine flags: -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:GCLogFileSize=2097152 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:InitialHeapSize=1149239296 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=45 -XX:+ManagementServer -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:MaxHeapSize=1149239296 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -XX:MetaspaceSize=100663296 -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:+UseStringDeduplication

2017-07-05T20:13:10.591+0800: 38.999: [Full GC (Heap Inspection Initiated GC)  47M->13M(1096M), 0.0710197 secs]
   [Eden: 48.0M(54.0M)->0.0B(54.0M) Survivors: 0.0B->0.0B Heap: 47.5M(1096.0M)->13.2M(1096.0M)], [Metaspace: 15845K->15845K(1062912K)]
 [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.02, real=0.07 secs]

 num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
   1:         27256        5409512  [C
   2:          2889        3734776  [B
   3:            28         935336  [J
   4:         26366         632784  java.lang.String
   5:          4464         392832  java.lang.reflect.Method
   6:          2964         338128  java.lang.Class
   7:          9495         303840  java.util.HashMap$Node
   8:          1566         203296  [I
   9:          2576         167120  [Ljava.lang.Object;
  10:           971         120680  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
  11:          3610         115520  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
  12:          3335          69056  [Ljava.lang.Class;
  13:           924          67912  [Ljava.lang.String;
  14:          1697          67880  java.lang.ref.Finalizer
  15:          1608          64320  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
  16:          1232          59136  java.util.HashMap
  17:           652          52160  java.lang.reflect.Constructor
  18:          3243          51888  java.lang.Object
  19:          1453          46496  java.util.Hashtable$Entry
  20:          1027          41080  java.util.TreeMap$Entry
  21:           711          39816  java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream
  22:           708          39648  java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream
  23:           308          37176  [Ljava.lang.reflect.Method;
  24:           764          36672  org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.AttributeInfo
  25:            56          31968  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node;
  26:           442          31824  java.lang.reflect.Field
  27:            30          31200  [[C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case GC is caused by `-XX:+PrintClassHistogram` option. This flag forces heap inspection accompanied by Full GC in response to `SIGQUIT` signal.

As you can find from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059), `jstack` uses `SIGQUIT` to initiate communication with the target JVM. The same answer explains why `jstack` works under tomcat user, but not under root.

In short, `SIGQUIT` (also known as kill -3) plays two roles: to initiate Dynamic Attach and to dump JVM state. If Dynamic Attach fails, then JVM proceeds with heap inspection, and that in turn causes Full GC, because `-XX:+PrintClassHistogram` option is on.

Comment: Thanks. A more question, why heap inspection cause Full GC?

Comment: @linbo Because `-XX:+PrintClassHistogram` was programmed to count only reachable (alive) objects. See [the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/75d40493551f/src/share/vm/runtime/os.cpp#l275).

Comment: Enable PrintClassHistogram, looks Full GC is unavoidable if execute jstack with wrong user.