# Get VMVersionMismatchException when using jmap command

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

my jdk version is 1.8.0_111 and I'm reading a book on JVM. When I tried the command `jmap -F 6469`, an exception is thrown as below:

```
Attaching to process ID 6469, please wait...
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMVersionMismatchException: Supported versions are 25.111-b14. Target VM is 25.152-b11
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMVersionMismatchException: Supported versions are 25.111-b14. Target VM is 25.152-b11
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupVM(HotSpotAgent.java:435)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:305)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:140)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PMap.main(PMap.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
    at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VMVersionMismatchException: Supported versions are 25.111-b14. Target VM is 25.152-b11
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM.checkVMVersion(VM.java:227)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM.<init>(VM.java:294)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VM.initialize(VM.java:370)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupVM(HotSpotAgent.java:431)
    ... 11 more
```

It seems there is something wrong with my jvm version, but I can't find out why. I'm new to JVM, and I'd be grateful if someone could tell me why and how to deal with it.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple JDKs (or additional JREs) installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The target process (6469) runs under different version of JRE (1.8.0_152).

When running `jmap` or `jstack` in forced mode (-F), JDK version of the tool must be exactly the same as JDK of the target process.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue on ubuntu, after changing the java path.

Edit java path

`sudo gedit /etc/profile`

change the java path

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`
(set the java path which java version you are using)

restart the system.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows one can use `psexec` so we don't have to use the `-F` option. So you don't have to use the same exact jdk version for `jhat` and the for the java process.

This is useful when the jdk with the same exact version is not available. Say for instance, in a bigger organisation sometimes folks only update the jvm, but do not install the same jdk on the production system.

The `psexec` is part of the `PsTools` bundle. You can find them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). Here is what the command would look like:

```
F:\Programs\PSTools\PsExec.exe -s jmap.exe <pid>
```

Even with psexec one might need sufficient rights.