# analysis of a java process "not responding"?

Tags: java, jvm, jstack, jstat

My java process stopped responding. I tried to jstack but failed with below error.

```
21039: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

Then I used -F option, but "No deadlocks found."

Other info:

java version: [java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6JGE.png)

jmap: [jmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkO8T.png)

jstat: [jstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ua7oD.png)

jinfo: [jinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuHtH.png)

Can anyone help have a look and share some links on troubleshooting this kind of java "not responding" issue?

Answer (score 4):

Possible reasons of `Unable to open socket file` problem:

1. The target PID is not a HotSpot JVM process.
   This is obviously not your case, since `jinfo PID` works fine.
2. JVM is started with `-XX:+DisableAttachMechanism` option.
   This can be also verified by `jinfo PID`.
3. Attach socket `/tmp/.java_pidNNN` has been deleted.
   There is a common practice to clean `/tmp` automatically with some scheduled script. In this case you should configure the cleanup software not to delete `.java_pid*` files.

   How to check: run `lsof -p PID | grep java_pid`
   If it lists a socket file, but the file does not exist, then this is exactly the described problem.
4. Credentials of the current user (`euid`/`egid`) do not match the owner of the attach socket. Make sure you run `jstack` by the same user as JVM. Attach won't work if you run `jstack` by a different user, even if this user is `root`.
5. `/tmp` directory of the target process is not the same as `/tmp` of your shell. This may happen in the following cases:

   - JVM is started in a different [mount namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html). Typically this happens when JVM runs in a Docker container. Running `jstack` from within the same container will help.
   - JVM is started in [`chroot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) environment. For example, LXC containers may use `chroot`.
     How to check: run `readlink -f /proc/PID/root/tmp` to see if it points to `/tmp` or to some other directory.
6. Current working directory of the target JVM belongs to a file system that does not allow to change permissions. [CIFS](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) and [DrvFs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/12/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/) (WSL) are examples of such file systems.

   How to check: run `umask 077; touch /proc/PID/cwd/somefile.tmp`, then verify that file owner is yourself, and file permissions are `600`.
7. JVM is busy and cannot reach a safepoint. For instance, JVM is in the middle of long-running garbage collection.

   How to check: run `kill -3 PID`. JVM should print a thread dump and heap info in its console. If JVM does not dump anything, but the process consumes almost 100% CPU or shows high I/O utilization, then this looks like the described problem.
8. JVM process is suspended.

   How to check: run `ps PID`. The `STAT` column of alive JVM process should be `Sl`.

[More about the internals of jstack.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059)

There is also [`jattach`](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) project which is a better alternative to `jstack` / `jmap`. It can automatically handle credentials issue, it works with Docker containers, supports chroot'ed JVMs and handles uncommon file systems.