# Jmap error "More than one non-option argument"

Tags: java, debugging, jvm

I'm trying to convert JVM core dump to HPROF format with following command 
`jmap -dump:format=b,file=dump.hprof $(which java) core.dump.9`

and getting the following error

```
Error: More than one non-option argument
Cannot connect to core dump or remote debug server. Use jhsdb jmap instead
```

What am I doing wrong and are there other tools to convert it? JDK is OpenJDK 11.0.4.

Comment: Changing it to `/usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java` doesn't help

Comment: Suggestion: type `cd /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java/bin; ./pmap` and see if the options are all valid with OpenJDK11.  If they are, then type `./pmap dump:format=b,file=dump.hprof /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java /path/to/file/core.dump.9`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since JDK 9 `jmap` works only with a live JVM through the [Dynamic Attach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963059/3448419) mechanism.

The 'forced' mode `jmap -F` was replaced with a separate utility [jhsdb](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jhsdb.html).

Use the following command to produce a heap dump from a core file:

```
jhsdb jmap --binaryheap --dumpfile dump.hprof --exe /usr/local/openjdk-11/bin/java --core core.dump.9
```