# Why doesn't jvm command `jinfo` have `-flags` in alpine openjdk8 distribution?

Tags: java, docker, jvm, alpine-linux

I used docker to build a java program, the beginning of the Dockerfile is

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
```

but I notice the jvm command jinfo has no `-flags`, what is wrong?

```
    bash-4.4# ./jinfo
    Usage:
        jinfo <option> <pid>
           (to connect to a running process)

    where <option> is one of:
        -flag <name>         to print the value of the named VM flag
        -flag [+|-]<name>    to enable or disable the named VM flag
        -flag <name>=<value> to set the named VM flag to the given value
        -h | -help           to print this help message
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDK for Alpine is built without [Serviceability Agent](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bsa) support, because SA relies on the features that musl [does not have](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/portola-dev/2017-April/000082.html).

Some JDK utilities use Serviceability Agent under the hood for certain functions. `jinfo -flags` is an example of such utility. Other examples that also use SA under the hood are `jmap -F` and `jstack -F`. These options are also unavailable in Alpine JDK.
In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963059/3448419) I described how the forced mode (`-F`) differs from the normal mode, and what role Serviceability Agent plays there.

`jinfo -flags` can be replaced with `jcmd <pid> VM.flags`.

`jcmd` does not rely on SA, and it works on Alpine Linux.