Queued Thread Pool High CPU Usage
I have a Java process consuming upwards of 400% CPU on my server (AlmaLinux) which shouldn’t be the case.
On my analysis I find multiple QTPs (Queued Thread Pools) consuming the CPU:

After analysing a Thread Dump and comparing the NIDs, the QTPs that are consuming CPU are in WAITING and TIMED_WAITING states, for example:
This one is PID(NID) 3221507 which alone consumes 21%:
"qtp737077247-58814" #58814 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f60e0002000 nid=0x312803 runnable [0x00007f61125f0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ed507048> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(QueuedThreadPool.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:609)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

And this one for example PID(NID) 3183314 which is eating 23%:
"qtp737077247-58803" #58803 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f60fc001800 nid=0x3092d2 waiting on condition [0x00007f61b1606000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ed507028> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.offer(BlockingArrayQueue.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.execute(QueuedThreadPool.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Now I have no idea why a WAIT is eating so much CPU. I have seen this question but not much seems to help.
An interesting point is that I have the same process running on other machines (Windows) that do not ever get to this point of CPU usage, keeping it to the normal, expected values.
Any idea where I can steer my analysis here?

What version of the JVM do you use?  Also what's the version of your *nix too please.  If possible, I think it would also help to show us all parameters passed to the JVM when it starts up.

This might help, "timed wait" is basically a thread waiting with a timeout. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62293140/what-is-the-difference-between-thread-state-waiting-parking-vs-blocked-at-sun

WAITING and TIMED_WAIT does not consume any CPU at all. Those are threads waiting for a task.

Did you only take one thread dump? You could just be “lucky” and catch a thread between tasks. What are other similar threads doing? It might be more helpful to use a sampling profiler.

@TimMoore i have two similar servers with the same situation, so 2 thread dumps that report exactly the same, some WAITing QTPs eating up the CPU, both servers are AlmaLinux, one is 8.10 and the other is 8.7. Both use openjdk 8_352

@MarkRotteveel these are clearly using CPU. 0x312803 translates to TID 3221507 which declares 21% CPU, same with 0x3092d2 (3183314), which eats 23% CPU.
These do seem to "spin around" since right now, these threads are no longer there, there are just another same amount of QTPs eating up 20-30% cpu each.

I hope @JohnSkeet will notice this. I wonder when...
