# Capturing thread dump using kill -3

Tags: java, jvm, kill, thread-dump

Trying to capture thread dump to a file using kill -3

Tried

-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=dump.log

This works but looking for something like

```
jstack 17264 > /tmp/threaddump.txt
```

Any simple way to capture thread dump using kill -3 and output to a file using command

Comment: Well, you already know how to get a thread dump with `kill -3`, and how to get a thread dump using `jstack`. What else do you miss and why?

Comment: @apangin I am looking to redirect the output to a file using the command kill -3 same like jstack example i have given

Comment: Why can't you use jstack then? JVM's SIGINT handler dumps threads to the JVM's standard output, and it has no option to redirect output other than the flag you've already mentioned.

Comment: Sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @apangin If the app is unresponsive or sick and if I try jstack using -f then that thread dumps has its own issues, the best option maybe to use kill -3

Comment: `jstack` (without -F) and `kill -3` use the same mechanism to get a thread dump under the hood. They both rely on the cooperation from the JVM; in both cases the threads are dumped at the global VM safepoint. If the JVM hangs, `kill -3` will not help either.

Comment: @apangin whats the best option to capture thread dumps without losing thread state, lock Ids, what app is about to get sick

Comment: There is no silver bullet. Either JVM works, and therefore it produces a nice thread dump on its own (in response to jstack or kill -3). Or it doesn't work, and the only way to get the information is through an external process that tries to read the foreign memory and reconstruct the JVM structures (this is what jstack -F does).

Comment: Here's also another great answer by @apangin which also mentions `gcore`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059