# Jmap does not have the file parameter, so the execution is abnormal. However, the execution is normal after the file parameter is added

Tags: java, jvm, jmap

The specific exception information is as follows:

```
root@test-6cf7db85b7-sxk8h:/# jmap 7
Attaching to process ID 7, please wait...
ERROR: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 7: Operation not permitted
Error attaching to process: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 7: Operation not permitted
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 7: Operation not permitted
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal$LinuxDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.execute(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:163)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:278)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:671)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerLinux(HotSpotAgent.java:611)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:337)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:304)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:140)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:185)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.PMap.main(PMap.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the process: ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ..) failed for 7: Operation not permitted
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.access$100(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:62)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal$1AttachTask.doit(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:269)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal$LinuxDebuggerLocalWorkerThread.run(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:138)

root@test-6cf7db85b7-sxk8h:/# ^C
root@test-6cf7db85b7-sxk8h:/#
```

The two commands are as follows:

```
// error
jmap 7
// success
jmap -dump:file=test.hprof 7
```

java info:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

Jmap does not have the file parameter, so the execution is abnormal. However, the execution is normal after the file parameter is added.

Comment: What is this “file parameter” you repeatedly talk about? Do you mean the `-dump` parameter?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In JDK 8, `jmap` and `jmap -dump` are actually two different utilities, indiscreetly packed in one executable.

They serve different purposes, and use different mechanisms under the hood:

- `jmap` (without arguments) is based on the HotSpot Serviceability Agent;
- `jmap -dump` uses Dynamic Attach.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059) for details about Serviceability Agent and Dynamic Attach, or read [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/creating-your-own-debugging-tools).

While Dynamic Attach usually works fine in most containers, Serviceability Agent requires [`CAP_SYS_PTRACE`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) capability, which is typically available only in a privileged container.

Since JDK 9, the oversight was finally fixed, and now Serviceability Agent tools are bundled in a separate utility named [`jhsdb`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jhsdb.htm).