# Issue Taking Java Heap Dump

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, heap-dump

I'm trying to take a java heap dump to help investigate a memory leak. Whenever I use this:

```
 jmap -J-d64 -dump:format=b,file=myheapdump -F 29498
```

The heap dump file gets to about 16,048 kb and stops growing, jmap will run forever and not stop unless I kill it. Alternatively I tried using this:

```
jcmd 29498 -F GC.heap_dump heapdump.hprof
```

But since I am executing it from root, and the process is being run from another user, I get this:

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
    at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:147)
    at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.java:131)
```

So I guess my question is what am I doing wrong and what is the best way to move forward in trying to get this heap dump?

Comment: What about running `jmap` (without -F) from the same user account as used to run JVM?

Comment: I get an error stating that the user does not have permission

Comment: What permission? To create a dump file? Try a different directory which the user has permission to write to.

Comment: Attempting to use jcmd as the process owner, and writing to a directory that is owned by the same user I get this: Permission denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around the error when using jcmd, you can try adding the jvm argument mentioned in this answer:
[com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438983/com-sun-tools-attach-attachnotsupportedexception-unable-to-open-socket-file-ta)

Another possibility if you're using Linux is to use the gdb tool as outlined here:
https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/so-you-want-your-jvms-heap

Comment: Adding that argument gives another error: 

jcmd 17272 -XX:+StartAttachListener  GC.heap_dump heapdump.hprof
17272:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown diagnostic command

Comment: @jymbo From that error message looks like you may have added the argument to the jcmd command itself? The arg would need to be added to the java command of the process which you are trying to get the dump of, when you start up that process