# Java - AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: HotSpot VM not loaded

Tags: java, linux, sockets, jvm, agent

When attempting to attach an agent jar file onto another process running in java, I have came across the exception:

***com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException:*** 
*Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded*

I was running linux, with java **Oracle JDK 8_101**, however after answering this question I've realized the O.S does not matter for the cause of this problem.

*Edit:*
***Answer:***

If you encounter this problem, the reason it occured for me is because I was launching a program from a different JVM, other than the default JVM specified for the system.

i.e)

**Program** ***A*** ***(The launcher)***, is running on **JVM-1** *(JDK_8_1 for example, or JDK_8_1/jdk/jre)*.

**Program** ***A*** ***(The launcher)***, creates a process with ***java -jar programB.jar***

**Program** ***B*** ***(The target)***, is running on the system's default JVM, **JVM-2** *(JDK_8_2 for example, or JDK_8_2/jre)*.

**Program** ***A*** ***(The launcher)*** **CANNOT** attatch to 
**Program** ***B*** ***(The target)***, because the JVM **Program** ***A*** ***(The launcher)*** is running on, does not match the JVM of which **Program** ***B*** ***(The target)*** is running on, thus throwing the 
***com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException:***

Comment: You might increase the attach timeout (when it's related to timeout and not to permissions) `-Dsun.tools.attach.attachTimeout=10000` (the default is 5000). Could you post some code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Duplicate of a great https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Common reasons for this problem:

- Attach socket `/tmp/.java_pid1234` has been removed (e.g. by a scheduled job that periodically cleans up /tmp).
- Target JVM is started with `-XX:+DisableAttachMechanism` option.
- Garbage Collection or other long VM operation (e.g. Heap Dump) is in progress.
- JVM cannot reach safepoint within attach timeout. This happens rarely, and the problem is typically intermittent.

Comment: Thanks my man! Going to check out any schedulers for the tmp folder removal. Is there any way to specify the location which the file gets stored?

Comment: @JoeD Unfortunately, the location is hard-coded inside JVM. However, a process can be run in its own [mount namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) so that `/tmp` of a JVM process will differ from `/tmp` of the rest system.

Comment: For me it happened due to the missing `/tmp/.java_pidXXX file` (happened on HotSpot version 1.8.0_281 and RHEL 8.3 OS).
But another time it was due to using another user to launch the jcmd/jmap command as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51507597/1996150 answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem: different user executing jcmd**

It might happen, that the user calling jcmd is different, than the user running the proccess.

Example:

- user invoking jcmd as root
- user running JVM as fancyUser

Solution:

On Linux try to run jcmd with the same user, as the process is running.

When you have such a scenario, you will get given error.

**Problem: AppArmor**

When AppArmor is enabled for running JVM instance, which restricts sys-calls, it might be the case, that opening a socket-connection is restricted.

Solution:

Change AppArmor-Profile for process