# jcmd's VM.command_line option available over time

Tags: java, java-8, jcmd

I am running jcmd with the VM.command_line option as shown below To get the JavaVM startup command running in the server.

```
jcmd {proccessId} VM.command_line
```

This will return the following error over time.

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
        at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:147)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.java:131)
```

The time depends on the content of the application running on the Java VM.
In some environments, the error will occur in 10 days, while in other environments, the error will occur in 27 days.

When investigating from the error content
[Java - AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: HotSpot VM not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379878/java-attachnotsupportedexception-unable-to-open-socket-file-hotspot-vm-not-l)

The error that occurs when executed by a user who is not the JavaVM startup user,
The user has not changed this event before and after the passage of time.
The cause cannot be identified because an error occurs over time.
The above error does not occur when restarting the Java process
However, after a while (about 10 days), the error occurs again.

I am in need because I cannot identify the cause.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Did you try looking at the source code for class `sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine`? You can easily find it on the Internet. I found [this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/solaris/classes/sun/tools/attach/LinuxVirtualMachine.java) You may even be able to modify the code and add debugging details and then replace the class in the relevant JAR file with your class.