# Running jcmd using JDK-11 on JDK-8 java process not running successfully

Tags: java, jcmd

I am trying to monitor native memory of tomcat using jcmd but getting following exception:
Command: `jcmd 14533<pid of tomcat> VM.native_memory summary`

I have installed 2 `jdk's` `jdk-11` AND `jdk-8`.

Tomcat is running by `jdk-8` and jcmd used `jdk-11` then i got following exception:

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file /proc/31752/root/tmp/.java_pid31752: target process 31752 doesn't respond within 10500ms or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineImpl.<init>(VirtualMachineImpl.java:100)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.AttachProviderImpl.attachVirtualMachine(AttachProviderImpl.java:58)
    at jdk.attach/com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:207)
    at jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:114)
    at jdk.jcmd/sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.java:98)
```

I attched `-XX:+StartAttachListener` with java process but it didn't work.

Comment: Hope this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438983/com-sun-tools-attach-attachnotsupportedexception-unable-to-open-socket-file-ta

Answer (score 1):

If you are running tomcat as a service on linux check following config in unit file i.e. tomcat.service

1. PrivateTmp=yes, should be removed. As PrivateTmp=yes create private /tmp folder which is not accessible by tool
2. If you have ProtectSystem=strict, add ReadWritePaths=/tmp/

Go through man page for systemd unit file config

Answer (score 0):

It can be a user permission issue: jmap has to be run with the same user as the java process. e.g. if the owner is `usera` and this is running in a docker contained execute jmap as user `usera`

```
docker exec --user usera -it container_id jmap -dump:format=b,file=/home/usera/memorydump.bin 1
```