# Create JVM heap dump of tomcat service running on Window

Tags: jvm, heap-dump, jmap, jcmd

While trying to create a heap dump from a Tomcat Service running as windows service, get "Access is denied" error. I started the command prompt as "Run as Administrator"

[Erorr while using jmap and jcmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wFRg.png)

How do I get rid of "Access is denied" or is there a different way to create the heap dump?

Comment: Have you tried getting a heap dump via visualvm?

Comment: Try to run it under the _same user as the tomcat service is running_. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438983/com-sun-tools-attach-attachnotsupportedexception-unable-to-open-socket-file-ta. You can also check https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-do-I-capture-a-Java-heap-dump-in-Windows/ta-p/24170

Comment: I was able to create heap dump using Jconsole by adding a JMX port to the tomcat service. VisualVM was giving a generic error saying operation didn't succeed, couldn't trace more to see why it failed. Thanks!